# Object Serialization in Java Behaviour of readObject()

Tags: java, object, serialization

Let's say I have a Person class and I am using `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` with a `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` to read and write the object to a file. 
If i have various objects of class Person, for example *person1*, *person2*, *person3*
and i use

```
writeObject(person1)
writeObject(person2)
writeObject(person3)
```

When I do

```
Person p1 = (Person) in.readObject()
```

will *p1* be equal to *person1* or *person3*? In other words, does `readObject` follow a stack or queue sort of behaviour. Does it read the objects in the order they were written or does it read them in the reverse order?

Comment: You can easily test this and get your answer. But to make it shorter: it will read the objects in the order they were written.

Comment: Here's a helpful section from the [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4176)

Answer (score 0):

> will p1 be equal to person1 or person3? In other words, does
>   readObject follow a stack or queue sort of behaviour. Does it read the
>   objects in the order they were written or does it read them in the
>   reverse order?

`readObject()` method read an object from the ObjectInputStream in the same order in which they are written to the stream. So in your case `p1` will be equal to person1. Here is an example

```
import java.io.*;


public class Example {

   static class Person implements Serializable {
      String name;

      public Person(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Person{" +
                 "name='" + name + '\'' +
                 '}';
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Person person1 = new Person("Adam");
      Person person2 = new Person("John");
      try {

         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
         ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

         oout.writeObject(person1);
         oout.writeObject(person2);
         oout.flush();

         ObjectInputStream ois =
                 new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.txt"));

         System.out.println("" +  ois.readObject());
         System.out.println("" +  ois.readObject());


      } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

It outputs

```
Person{name='Adam'}
Person{name='John'}
```

The same order in which objects were written via

```
oout.writeObject(person1);
 oout.writeObject(person2);
```